# Как получить кол-во выбранных значений из списка?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Помогите разобраться, есть следующая функция на JS

```
function fieldsShowWhenObjChanged() {
        var filterObjTypeVal = $('#FilterObjectType').val();
        $('#case_number').css('display', filterObjTypeVal == "CLAIM" ? '' : 'none');
        $('#srv_services').css('display', filterObjTypeVal == "SRV_SERVICE" ? '' : 'none');

        if (filterObjTypeVal == "SRV_SERVICE") {
            $("#FilterServiceCode").multipleSelect({
                selectAllText: 'Выбрать все Услуги',
                allSelected: 'Показывать все Услуги',
                minimumCountSelected: 1,
                countSelected: 'выбрано # из %',
                placeholder: 'Выберите Услуги',
                filter: true
            });
        }
    }
```

она все правильно отрабатывает(выводит кол-во выбранных элементов из списка), но мне не понятно, что делает эта строка `countSelected: 'выбрано # из %'`, что значит `# из %`?

Само приложение представляет из себя MVC, элементы для списка выбираются из модели C#, вот код

```
<select class="condition markup-select" style="width: 100%" id="FilterObjectType" name="FilterObjectType" onchange="fieldsShowWhenObjChanged()">
                                <option value="">Показывать все</option>
                                @foreach (TABLE_ID tableId in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TABLE_ID)).Cast<TABLE_ID>())
                                {
                                    <option value="@tableId" @(Model.State.Filter.FilterObjectType == tableId.ToString() ? "selected=selected" : "")>@tableId.GetDescription()</option>
                                }
                            </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multipleSelect - какая то из многих либ для жквери, вероятнее всего внутри выполняется `countSelected.replace('%', число всех объектов).replace('#', число выбранных объектов)`

Советую покопаться в исходниках этой функции и посмотреть что под капотом

Comment: @Nikta M. спасибо, попробую